# String Column Needs Date Conversion MySQL

Tags: mysql

I looked all over this site and couldn't locate my example. I'm working on a mysql project using a BI application that allows us to use MySql.

Data needing conversion:

Wed Jun 01 2022 05:04:03 GMT

Desired output :
2022-06-01T00:20:29-05:00
We used UTC to get this result on another column.

I tried

```sql
STR_TO_DATE('Wed Jun 01 2022', '%Y %M %D')
```

Comment: Does this have to be done with a query? php, for example, has much more sophisticated date and time tools.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the right direction with the `STR_TO_DATE` mysql function, you just need to use the right [specifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

You can then use `CONVERT_TZ` to change the timezone from GMT to -05:00 and  DATE_FORMAT to convert the date back to a string in the right format. There is no specifier for the timezone/offset so you can just append it using `CONCAT` (assuming you always want -05:00).

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Wed Jun 01 2022 05:04:03 GMT', '%W %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s');
-- output 2022-06-01 05:04:03

SELECT CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE('Wed Jun 01 2022 05:04:03 GMT', '%W %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s'), 'GMT', '-05:00');
-- output 2022-06-01 00:04:03

SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE('Wed Jun 01 2022 05:04:03 GMT', '%W %b %d %Y %H:%i:%s'), 'GMT', '-05:00'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'), '-05:00');
-- output 2022-06-01T00:04:03-05:00
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error on the last '-5:00' . the original output is in this format: Wed Jun 03 2022 05:20:5 GMT+0000(Coordinated Universal Time)

Comment: Can you share the error details and an isolated code fragment to reproduce the error?